# About an inequality contain epsilon greater than 0

Tags: inequality

If I have $ B-\epsilon < A $ for all $\epsilon > 0$, can I say $ B \leq A $? or $ B < A $? Thanks

Comment: $B\leq A$.  [1] Suppose that $B > A$, and obtain a contradiction. [2] Suppose that $B = A$ rather than $B < A$.  Demonstrate that this situation does not violate the constraint.  Remember, you are only concerned about $\epsilon > 0$, rather than $\epsilon \geq 0.$

Comment: Therefore, you mean that $ B-\epsilon <A $ means that $ B-A< \epsilon $ which means that $B -A $ is smaller than all positive numbers, so $B-A$ can't greater than 0 (B can't greater than A) because otherwise $ B-A $ will be greater some positive numbers. However, $B=A $ and $B<A$ make sense because  $B-A$ is smaller than any positive numbers, it can only be zero or negative. Therefore $B \leq A$. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, that is one way of looking at it.  Actually, I intended a different but similar idea: suppose that $B = A$.  Is it possible to **then** find an $\epsilon > 0$ such that it is not the case that $(B - \epsilon) < A$?  Either you can find such an $\epsilon$, or you can not find such an $\epsilon$.  If you can prove that it is impossible to find such an $\epsilon$, then you have proven that $B = A$ does not violate the constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to visualise it (not prove it) is look at some examples. We have $B < A + 1$, $B < A + 0.1$, $B < A + 0.01$ etc. Then notice that $B = A$ satisfy all of these requirements: $A < A + 0.1$, $A < A + 0.01$ etc. So we have $B = A$ is fine, and obviously all $B < A$ is perfectly okay as well.

We can write it out as $\forall \epsilon > 0, B - \epsilon < A \implies \forall \epsilon > 0, A - B > -\epsilon$, and so $A - B\geq 0$ and $A\geq B$.